# OpenXML C#: Cannot get hold of rectangle embedded in Chart (Word-doc)

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I have a Word document with a chart. That chart has two rectangles where I want to get txBody to change the text.

What I know:

- The Chart has rId17
- The Uri is /word/charts/chart2.xml *(DrawingML as far as I can see)*
- The Uri of ChartDrawingPart is /word/drawings/drawing1.xml
- drawing1.xml has the txBody I need:

```
<cdr:txBody>
  <a:bodyPr xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" vertOverflow="clip" lIns="54000" rIns="54000"/>
  <a:lstStyle xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/>
    <a:p xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
        <a:pPr algn="ctr"/>
        <a:r>
          <a:rPr lang="da-DK"/>
          <a:t>BB</a:t>
        </a:r>
    </a:p>
</cdr:txBody>
```

- If I could just somehow get hold of that with DocumentFormat.OpenXml (C#) I should be able to change the text

Using C# and DocumentFormat.OpenXml I have tried a lot of different approaches:
*(I managed to change paragraphs, contentcontrols, graphs/charts and tables in the doc, but not the rectangles in a given chart)*

*(doc is WordprocessingDocument)*

```
doc.MainDocumentPart?.ChartParts;
```

-> Iterating through chartSpaceChildElem I can find the chart (chart2.xml) - (I can change Numericvalues but I can't find the Rectangles)
As I see it I'm working on chart2.xml but I need to get to drawing1.xml

I tried:

```
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Drawing>()
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<UserShapes>()
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Shape>()
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Chart>()
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<ExternalData>()
doc.MainDocumentPart?.ImageParts
doc.MainDocumentPart?.DiagramDataParts
```

and something like

```
chartSpaceChildElem.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office2016.Drawing.ChartDrawing.TxPrTextBody>()`
```

None of that got me what I wanted.

I think I can get all elements in MainDocumentPart (under /word). I.e. document, comments, footnotes etc. but drawing1.xml is under /word/drawings/ and I can't get to that?

Can someone show me how to use DocumentFormat.OpenXml with C# to grab that?
*(I don't want to stream the xml. as that would require me to unzip the word-doc)*

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to get hold of the usershapes.

I needed to use the ChartPart to get hold of UserShapes *(from ChartDrawingPart)*.
After that I can search for Descendants Shape

So there it is - I mentioned the URI of ChartDrawingPart, but could just use the object instead of directly getting hold of drawing1.xml

The code *(ChartPartEfterTitel finds the wanted ChartPart from the title given)*:

```
internal static void TilretUserShapes(WordprocessingDocument doc, string titel, List<string> shapeTekster)
{
    ChartPart? chartFundet = Grafer.ChartPartEfterTitel(doc, titel);
    if (chartFundet is null)
    {
        return;
    }
    UserShapes userShapes = chartFundet.ChartDrawingPart.UserShapes;
    IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ChartDrawing.Shape> shape = userShapes.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.ChartDrawing.Shape>();
    for (int i = 0; i < shape.Count(); ++i)
    {
        if (shapeTekster.Count() > i)
        {
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run? indsæt = shape.ElementAt(i).Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Run>().FirstOrDefault();
            DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text nyTekst = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text() { Text = shapeTekster[i] };
            indsæt.Text = nyTekst;
        }
    }
}
```